# Menus Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Tenho que fazer um site, daqueles com uma página apenas com scroll automático, mas no Wordpress. Qual é a função que eu posso usar que faz isso? Quero dizer, apenas as que trazem os itens do menu.

Comment: O que você já tentou ou pesquisou até aqui?

Comment: O que eu pesquisei? Hmm... dezenas de coisas "prontas" com plugins para leigos do tipo instala e vai. Mas não achei nada de funções para retornar os links em "ancoras" : (

Comment: http://streetsmash.com/infinite-scrolling-wordpress-themes/

Answer (score 1):

se for o que entendi voce pode usar este codigo (jquery)

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

[fonte](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)